# Where are %stored Jupyter files located?

Tags: jupyter, jupyter-notebook

The `%store` magic feature can save large python objects for you to use in between different sessions, but I'd like to find out where the files are actually located so I can also transfer them between different computers. I am using Windows 7.

Answer (score 7):

IPython does that, see github for [storemagic.py](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/blob/master/IPython/extensions/storemagic.py)

Stored value will be kept under `%IPYTHONDIR/<profile_name>/db/autorestore/<variable_name>`

Or by default `~/.ipython/profile_default/db/autorestore/<variable_name>`